# What does !type mean in this code?

Tags: java, operators

What does `!type` mean in the following snippet? Why put `!`?

```
String type = request.getParameter("tipo");
if (type == null) {
    out.print("ERROR: The field type wasn't selected<br>");
}
if (!type.equals("auto")
&&  !type.equals("trailer")
&&  !type.equals("motorcycle")) {
    out.print("ERROR: field error ("+type+")<br>");
}
```

Can somebody explain this codes to me especially `!type`?

Comment: not equal .....https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: It isn't `(!type).equals("auto")`, it's `!(type.equals("auto"))` i.e. the `.equals` part is evaluated first, and then `!` is applied to the result of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type is an instance of the `String` object, it has the method `String#equals(...)` and that method returns a `boolean`...

"**!**" this is the negation opeator and inverts any boolean value...

so
`!type.equals("auto")` is a `boolean` condition as result from comparing whether the String var with the name type has the value "auto" .

Answer (score 1):

'!' is a boolean operator and it just means NOT (Negation).

so !type.equals("auto") will evaluate to true if type is not "auto"

Answer (score 1):

! Is not , and equals() method return boolean and it means it returns true and false and then ! Will negative it , it makes true , false and false true for example:

```
String text = "test";

Text.equals("test") returns true
And !text.equals("test") returns false

Text.equals("example") returns false
And !text.equals("test") returns true
```

Or simply in your code it means check if the text is not equal to ...